# Forcing a timeout in git push + pull

Tags: git

all questions I found want to avoid timeouts in git push/pull. In my case I want to force them. My push + pulls are all going over ssh to remote machines that might be unavailable at some point in time. For example, I have a script that pushes to two remote public repos. I don't want that this script hangs forever when it pushes to the first repo and that machine is unavailable. Instead, after some timeout i want the push to fail and continue with the second repo.

Any options here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don’t think you can do an automatic fail-over with built-in features. But since Git just uses SSH underneath, it should work to add a `ConnectTimeout` option for the machines in question in your `.ssh/config`. Cf. [`man ssh_config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config). Then something like `git push foo || git push bar` in the shell should do what you want.

Comment: Hi, do both of them use ssh ?


git@github.com:neovim/neovim.git


https://github.com/neovim/neovim.git

Answer (score 1):

from https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/config.txt (around line 1770 at time of writing)

> http.lowSpeedLimit, http.lowSpeedTime::
>       If the HTTP transfer speed is less than 'http.lowSpeedLimit'
>       for longer than 'http.lowSpeedTime' seconds, the transfer is aborted.
>       Can be overridden by the 'GIT_HTTP_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT' and
>       'GIT_HTTP_LOW_SPEED_TIME' environment variables.

I call it the Codeplex tweak. Add it to your .gitconfig

`[http]
  lowSpeedLimit = 1000
  lowSpeedTime = 20`

Comment: What is Codeplex tweak ?

Comment: Codeplex was really slow so I had to set this to get it to work.