# Is there a way to make git over http timeout?

Tags: git, http, timeout, jenkins

I'm having a script running git clone/pull automatically (this is actually happening inside jenkins CI, but my question is more general). The remote git server is HTTPS based. The machine with the git client has a flaky DSL internet connection, so it sometimes reconnects and changes IP address, losing all its existing connections. When the connection fails while the git client is running, the client never succeeds but it doesn't fail with a timeout either, so my script hangs up.

I'd like to set up the client so it timeouts after some period (so the script can retry, or log a failure, or take any other action). But I didn't find any timeout option in the git-config manpage. I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758703/forcing-a-timeout-in-git-push-pull) but it's only for SSH connections. Do you know if there's an alternative for http servers?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58134432/11509478) if you want to patch `git` itself to gain environment variable `GIT_HTTP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` and/which_overrides `http.connecttimeout` in `~/.gitconfig`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try using

> ### `http.lowSpeedLimit`, `http.lowSpeedTime`:
>
> If the HTTP transfer speed, in **bytes per second**, is less than 'http.lowSpeedLimit' for longer than 'http.lowSpeedTime' seconds, the transfer is aborted.
> Can be overridden by the `GIT_HTTP_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT` and
> `GIT_HTTP_LOW_SPEED_TIME` environment variables.

---

Git 2.41 (Q2 2023) added the unit for `http.lowSpeedLimit`.

See [commit 0aefe4c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0aefe4c8412087f8cf02f5cfcdde4f827a76c6d7) (13 May 2023) by [Corentin Garcia (`corenting`)](https://github.com/corenting).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1f141d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f141d6cb23b8b11be0412b96cd54fc867de7a2a), 20 May 2023)</sup>

> ### [`doc/git-config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0aefe4c8412087f8cf02f5cfcdde4f827a76c6d7): add unit for http.lowSpeedLimit
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Corentin Garcia</sup>

> Add the unit (bytes per second) for `http.lowSpeedLimit` in the documentation.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0aefe4c8412087f8cf02f5cfcdde4f827a76c6d7/Documentation/config/http.txt#L249-L251):

> If the HTTP transfer speed, in bytes per second, ...

Comment: This seemed to work, thanks. At least I haven't seen the problem for a while.

Comment: @manojlds what is the unit of http.lowSpeedLimit do i set it as 10kbps

Answer (score 26):

Additional to *CAD bloke*'s answer:

Also

```
git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 1000
git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 600
```

works fine.

The above example means the remote action will block when the speed kept below 1KB/s for 600 seconds(10min), the action will block.

Comment: It definitely doesn't work. Try with: `git clone --verbose --mirror --depth=1 http://git.deha.vn:1080/bienhoang/deha-command.git`

Answer (score 11):

Add this to .gitconfig ...

```
[http]
lowSpeedLimit = 1000
lowSpeedTime = 20
```

lowSpeedLimit is bytes per second

I call it the Codeplex clause.

Comment: Explain the reasoning behind the name "Codeplex clause".

Comment: Codeplex was really slow back in the day.