# Timeout setting on git svn fetch operation

Tags: git, git-svn

I need to set the timeout on git svn fetch command. The fetch process should be timed out if it takes more than specific time interval(say 10 mins).Is it possible do like this in git command itself ? Or any other possible way to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make git over http timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458790/is-there-a-way-to-make-git-over-http-timeout)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58134432/11509478) if you want to patch `git` itself to gain environment variable `GIT_HTTP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` and/which_overrides `http.connecttimeout` in `~/.gitconfig`

Answer (score 6):

In Linux use [`timeout` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout):

```
timeout 10m git svn fetch
```