# Check whether a git remote is reachable

Tags: bash, git, ssh

In a bash script I want to cycle over all git remotes like so

```
for remote in $(git remote)
do
  git remote prune $remote
done
```

The problem is that in my case the `git remote` command for a currently not available remote does not timeout in a reasonable amount of time but just hangs.

How can I write the script so that it just ignores git remotes that are not currently available?

#### update:

The git connection happens via ssh.

Comment: maybe you can have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/227509/git-ping-check-if-remote-repository-exists

Comment: Also worth checking https://stackoverflow.com/q/6458790/469210

Comment: @olibiaz the `git ls-remote` command shows the same behavior and  does not timeout.

Comment: @borrible Setting http.lowSpeedTime and http.lowSpeedLimit does not change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are connecting using `ssh`, would it be worth configuring a timeout for `ssh`, so bad connections at least fail eventually? Certainly for my command line `ssh`, `ConnectTimeout` appears not to be set:

```
$ ssh -G git.example.com | grep -i ConnectTimeout
connecttimeout none
```

The `ConnectTimeout` setting is described in `man ssh_config` and is usually just put in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
ConnectTimeout 30
```